# Как из одного модуля передать данные в другой?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Приложение на *реакте*, есть главный модуль *Main*, в который подключает модуль *A* и модуль *B*.

Модуль *А* запрашивает данные с сервера, получает их и фильтрует, после чего добавляет в массив.

Как мне данные (массив) передать из модуля *А* в модуль *B*, если они не связаны между собой, то есть модуль *А* и модуль *B* подгружаются в модуль *Main* и в нем же отрисовываются?

*Как вариант:* делать запрос в самом модуле *Main*, обрабатывать эти данные и передавать их в модуль *В*? Но мне кажется, это неверно, ведь данные, которые относятся к модулю *А* лучше в нем и обрабатывать.

Также, фильтрация данных зависит от поведения модуля *А*, то есть, если я сделал какие-то манипуляции на *UI* в этом модуле, то фильтр данных, которые будут передаваться, изменятся, соответственно данные нужно передавать из модуля *А*. Вот как это сделать?

Comment: Использовать событие или коллбек?

Comment: я имею в виду, можно как-то модуль B подключить к А, чтоб передать ему данные?

Comment: А я имею в виду один из этих способов: 1. Компонент A вызывает коллбек в компоненте Main, тот прокидывает данные в компонент B, который сам перестраивается. 2. Компонент A рассылает уведомление об изменении, компонент B слушает это событие и при возникновении обновляет своё состояние.

Comment: а можно пример второго способа? ссылку например или буду признателен, если вы напишете хоть на коленке, как это происходит?

Comment: Ну любая система publish-subscribe. Возможно, flux. Я пока с реактом не работал, хотя собираюсь.

Comment: Все-таки было бы неплохо, если бы вы показали хоть какую-то структуру кода. Некий скелет приложения. Мне кажется (возможно слишком дилетантский взгляд, поскольку реактом тоже не пользовался) что, поскольку реакт "заточен" на интерфейсной части, вам следуем добавить отдельный модуль, который будет "моделью" вашего приложения, а модуль `Main` будет связывать всё воедино.

Comment: [Дополнение ReactLink](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) для организации связи «против течения» может быть тут полезен?

Answer (score 2):

Точный ответ зависит от сценария.

1. Если речь идет о наборе данных, который нужен двум компонентам, независимо друг от друга и просто не хочется делать два запроса на сервер - подумайте о кэшировании на уровне вашего слоя сервисов для доступа к данным.
2. Если один компонент загружает данные, обрабатывает их и нужно одностороннее  уведомление о том, что обработаны некие данные,то раздел [Communicate Between Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) из документации гласит:

> For communication between two components that don't have a parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event system.

Для реализации такого сценария вам может подойти, например, библиотека `PubSubJS`

3. Если речь идет о данных, к которым нужен совместный доступ двух и более модулей, и каждый должен знать об изменении этих данных другими, то вам может помочь `state container`. Hапример: `Redux`.

Answer (score 0):

React, сам по себе, беспомощен: в комплекте всегда должна идти библиотека для передачи данных и событий между компонентами.

Оригинальный стек Facebook называется React/Flux. Но Flux оказался довольно сложным и непонятным. Поэтому сейчас наиболее хайповое решение это библиотеква Redux. Она очень простая, крутая и удобная.

Но в принципе есть и другие варианты, например библиотека Baobab.